# Regular Expression to match groups correctly

Tags: regex

I am looking to parse custom markdown text such as the examples below.

```
1
Post:1
Image:1|thumb
Image:1|thumb|html classes here
1|thumb|html classes here
```

General format: `ModelName:ID|image_size|html classes`

Everything except the id after the colon (:) is optional. Note that the id can also be a string. There can be a number of space separated css classes after the last pipe. This is what I have so far:

```
^([\w\.]+)?(?::([-\w\d\.]+))(?:\|(\w+))?(?:\|([-\w\s\d]+))?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_gmIhqAT9nIhp96Y)

This regular expression has several issues that I can't figure out how to fix

1. The colon should appear before the line that merges into main, not after. In other words, the colon is only required if Group 1 is present. (Same idea as with the pipe (|) before group 3 and 4.
2. The regex does not match the last 3 test cases at the top. `1` and `Post:1` are matched correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with

```
(?:(\w+):)?(\d+)(?:[^|\n]*\|([^|\n]*)(?:\|(.*))?)?
```

It'll capture the first *tag* in group 1, the ID into the 2nd group, the image size into the 3rd and classes into the 4th.

First it captures a *tag* (optional), then a number. Followed by that a group, also optional,  that scans for `|`, and then capture everything up to another `|`or end of line. If a `|` was found capture everything to the end of line.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nK9wX4/6).

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely a step in the right direction. However, I need to capture Image and Post in a group as well.

Comment: Edited as per you comment :)

Comment: I edited your original regex and arrived at the same answer!! Thanks for your help. You're a regex expert!